# how to convince website users to use openid

Tags: openid

Perhaps this isn't the best forum for this question.  If so, would one of the other child sites be more suitable?

I am wondering how to overcome the learning curve of convincing a non-technical bunch of users how and what open id is.  how do you convince users that it is a good thing and that they want to use it?

Comment: I was amazed to see that I have 77 accounts linked to my openid (google)! That means there's 77 registration forms, email confirmations and new passwords that I *didn't* have to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you have to be willing to give up some percentage of your potential users by doing this. I'm not sure if it's 5% or 50%, but some number of users wont be willing to go to the extra effort of setting up & using OpenID just to use your service.

I suggest just making it easy for them to use OpenID, with icons that link to Facebook / Google / Yahoo / other big-name providers, and then to the side, another box that allows them to create an account directly on your site without OpenID (so you don't lose the users that don't want OpenID for whatever reason).

Answer (score 3):

By offering a service that they want to use and requiring they register with openid to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is lots of effort being put into how to make OpenID work (or at least non-Facebook-based Identity 2.0 in general) by Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, et al.

One of the more interesting recent projects is called [XAuth](http://xauth.org). Lots of the players got together and built a really cool preview of what could be done to make this stuff all work better: http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/18/spearheaded-by-meebo-xauth-looks-to-make-social-sites-smarter/

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you need to "convince" people means that maybe openid hasn't got it quite right yet.

Comment: no, people just don't want to try something new. Just because people still use IE6 doesn't mean its because FF, IE8, or Chrome all stink. :D

Answer (score 0):

The same way you 'make' anyone do anything: find out what they want and give it to them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an animation (something like this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q-IzScQiSM&feature=player_embedded))? Accompany it with the advantages of OpenId.

(Personally I'm not convinced on OpenId - Can't get past the fact that it theoretically could lead to man-in-the-middle attacks).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to just make all logins for your site use OpenID, and if users don't have one already, register them for one as part of the sign-up flow.  The [myOpenID Affiliate Program](https://www.myopenid.com/affiliate) is one way to do this.

A potential disadvantage is if you sign them up with a 3rd-party provider, it's quite possible they won't fully understand that they just got an OpenID from this other site (in this case, myOpenID), and they'll forget (or not be aware in the first place) of what their OpenID is.  If they choose to provide their email address, myOpenID will send them the welcome/confirmation email explaining it, but then you're trusting your users will read that.

Are your users likely to have an OpenID already?  In the US, it seems like most users already have an account with one of Google, Yahoo, or AOL, but I know that's not true of all demographics.